# LINQ group list and combine collections

Tags: c#, linq

Given these classes:

```
public class Employee
{
  public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
  public int GroupId { get; set; }
  public List<Plans> Plans { get; set; }
}

public class Plan
{
 public int PlanYearId { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And given a setup like so:

```
var employees = new List<Employee> {
    new Employee {
        EmployeeId = 1,
        GroupId = 1,
        Plans = new List<Plan> {
            new Plan {
                PlanReferenceId = 1111,
                Name = "Benefit 1"
            }}};
    new Employee {
        EmployeeId = 1,
        GroupId = 1,
        Plans = new List<Plan> {
            new Plan {
                PlanReferenceId= 2222,
                Name = "Benefit 2"
            },
            new Plan {
                PlanReferenceId= 2222,
                Name = "Benefit 3"
            }}}};
```

How can I use LINQ to group these employees by both EmployeeId and GroupId and then combine the two `List<Plan>` properties so that i would end up with something like this:

```
var employee = new Employee
{
    EmployeeId = 1,
    GroupId = 1,
    Plans = new List<Plan> {
        new Plan {
            PlanReferenceId = 1111,
            Name = "Benefit 1"
        },
        new Plan {
            PlanReferenceId = 2222,
            Name = "Benefit 2"
        },
        new Plan {
            PlanReferenceId = 2222,
            Name = "Benefit 3"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use combination of [`GroupBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501(v=vs.100).aspx) and [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var result = employees
    .GroupBy(e => new { e.EmployeeId, e.GroupId })
    .Select(g => new Employee
    {
        EmployeeId = g.Key.EmployeeId,
        GroupId = g.Key.GroupId,
        Plans = g.SelectMany(e => e.Plans).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I'll accept the answer in a few.

Comment: In GroupBy, you may want to create projection to have only relevant data in the Select clause:

GroupBy(e => new { e.EmployeeId, e.GroupId },e => e.Plans)